# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' while Using QuickBlox

Tags: ios, quickblox

while using Quickblox api for Simple chat getting eception

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:password:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x109e93cb8'
```

i just added all frameworks accordingly Quickblox Doc and called this method:

```
[QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:userName password:password successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user){
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
// error handling
NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);

NSError *error = (NSError*)response.error;

block (nil, error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing Other Linker Flag in Project build Settings

Go to the project build setting Search for "other linker flag" and add below flags there :

```
-lstdc++
-ObjC
-lxml2
```

Hope it will work.